# Testdisk 6.14 unable to fix 20GB WD ROM scroprio device

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, testdisk

Using partedmagic iso , with pre-configured utility testdisk 6.14 I tried to repair WD 20GB hard-disk. It failed in sense it got me "**read errors**".

I don't know how to fix it?

Please help me. I'm attaching testdisk.log as well on pastbin.

http://www.filedropper.com/testdisk

regards,

Comment: It sounds like that drive has hardware errors. It could just have localised damage, or it may be about to die totally. `testdisk` can't deal with problems like that. However, you may be able to rescue data from the drive. If you have enough spare space on another hard disk use [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) to try and save the partitions from the bad drive. `ddrescue` can save the filesystem off a partition to a normal file. You can use the loop device to mount such partition images. Also `testdisk` will happily work with such partition images.

Comment: Thanks @PM2Ring but how can i do rescue if there are no healthy partitions?

Comment: And if you're feeling particularly cautious you can duplicate the partition image file before you start using `testdisk` on it, so if you make a mistake you will still have a clean backup to work with.

Comment: If that drive is your only hard drive _please_ stop using that computer ASAP to minimize further possible damage to the filesystem. You will need a healthy drive to rescue data from the bad one. Do you know someone you can borrow a drive from? And you'll _seriously_ need to think about replacing the bad drive. As I said before, maybe the damage is localised and the rest of the drive is ok, but I certainly wouldn't risk my data using a drive like that.

Comment: I have used ddrescue GUI and it detects nothing. The version I'm using is bit old. Should i make use of cli or gui?

Comment: @PM2Ring  I have also included link of testdisk.log in org question.

Comment: I should also mention that it's a bad idea to rescue data from a bad partition to a healthy partition on the same hard drive. Copying data from one partition to another is rather intensive on the hardware, as the head has to keep jumping backwards & forwards between the partitions. That's not a great idea at the best of times (which is why I like to have at least 2 physical disks on my system when doing intensive operations on big files); it's a _really_ bad idea if the HD is suspected of imminent hardware failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20467/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-asadz).

Comment: @PM2Ring The output of both commands

./ddrescue -n /dev/old_disk /dev/new_disk rescued.log
# then try to recover as much of the dicy areas as possible:
./ddrescue -r 1 /dev/old_disk /dev/new_disk rescued.log

on ddrescue output screen shows
rescued: 0 B

ANY help